# Finding elevation of points using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, elevation

Which function and library do I use to find elevation of a set of points from shapefile in Python QGIS?

I have point shapefile and DEM with me.

Comment: By using 'identify' method of **QgsRasterDataProvider**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using 'identify' method of **QgsRasterDataProvider**. Next code can do that (you only need to change names of each layer for names of your layers):

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

point_layer = registry.mapLayersByName('random_points')
raster_layer = registry.mapLayersByName('utah_demUTM2')
rprovider = raster_layer[0].dataProvider()

points = [ feat.geometry().asPoint() for feat in point_layer[0].getFeatures() ]

values = [ rprovider.identify(point, QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results()[1]
           for point in points ]

for i, point in enumerate(points):
    print 'point: {}, value: {:.0f}'.format(point, values[i])
```

After running the code at Python Console of QGIS, it was obtained these values:

```
point: (390945,4.45115e+06), value: 1550
point: (459500,4.43215e+06), value: 1657
point: (428310,4.4389e+06), value: 1580
point: (440696,4.42605e+06), value: 1668
point: (455931,4.43519e+06), value: 2387
point: (462461,4.4274e+06), value: 1596
point: (474903,4.44233e+06), value: 2156
point: (447042,4.44411e+06), value: 1387
point: (445900,4.46419e+06), value: 1605
point: (411695,4.46731e+06), value: 1535
point: (439640,4.45529e+06), value: 1376
point: (369118,4.45867e+06), value: 2163
point: (364344,4.41719e+06), value: 1646
point: (389235,4.4248e+06), value: 1973
point: (461011,4.45046e+06), value: 2018
point: (438474,4.45699e+06), value: 1377
point: (366826,4.45125e+06), value: 2099
point: (361502,4.46407e+06), value: 1560
point: (452052,4.45705e+06), value: 2493
point: (448242,4.42587e+06), value: 2967
point: (366311,4.43337e+06), value: 2247
point: (368971,4.46071e+06), value: 1967
point: (393487,4.43411e+06), value: 1720
point: (400026,4.46377e+06), value: 2079
point: (449569,4.42784e+06), value: 2804
```

for layers in next image:

[image]